# How to change the selected range?

Tags: vba, excel, range

I have a macro that increases a value in a selected cell.

```
Sub add_1_to_the_selected_cell()
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 + 1
End Sub
```

and I want to write a macro that changes not only one cell but the selected range. How to do that?

Comment: For example `A1:C3` will be `A1:D4` ?

Comment: Try this `ActiveCell.Resize(numRows + 1, numColumns + 1).Select`

Comment: No. I want to increase the whole range. I select some range, run macro, and I want to have all these values increased.

Comment: What `A1:C3` should be increase ? When you run your program what range should it be ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the `Activecell` you will just have to use the [`Range` object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx) and a [`For Each` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ebk1751.aspx).

```
For Each c In Range("A1:C3")
    c.Value = c.Value + 1
Next c
```

If there are empty cells within the range which you do not want to add `1` onto, then just add in an `If` statement.

`If Not c.Value = vbNullString Then`

**EDIT:**

If you want to be able to select the range, and then run the macro, you can assign your selection to a `Range`, and then iterate through the `Range`.

```
Sub add1()
    Dim rngSelection As Range
    Set rngSelection = Selection

    For Each c In rngSelection
        If Not c.Value = vbNullString Then
            c.Value = c.Value + 1
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

Depending on the size of the `Range` you wish to perform this over, it could be more efficient to load the cells values into an array and perform the calculations within the array.

Comment: A1:C3 was just an example. The macro doesn't know what range will be selected. Your second code is that what I meant. Thank you.

Comment: Is `Dim rngSelection As Range`
    `Set rngSelection = Selection` necessary? Coudn't we just write `For Each c In Selection`?

Comment: Yeah you could just write that.. it would operate in exactly the same way. It's always good practice to declare variables though :)